# Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessSignaledException The process has been signaled with signal "11"

Tags: laravel, centos8, snappy

i am trying to convert html to pdf by using snappypdf laravel on CentOS Linux 8

Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessSignaledException^ {#863
-process: Symfony\Component\Process\Process^ {#861
-callback: null
-hasCallback: false
-commandline: "/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 --lowquality --margin-bottom '20' --margin-top '15' --orientation 'landscape' --page-size 'a3' --enable-javascript --footer-left '[page]' --footer-right '*Has Data Fault (True) = The data logger is transmitting data however with an issue such as sensor failure due to connectivity or damage.' '/tmp/knp_snappy619485d5cba579.63788877.html' '/tmp/knp_snappy619485d5cbae99.86089154.pdf'"
-cwd: "/var/www/html/ontotoreport"
-env: null
-input: null
-starttime: 1637123541.8356
-lastOutputTime: 1637123541.8983
-timeout: 60.0
-idleTimeout: null
-exitcode: 139
-fallbackStatus: []
-processInformation: array:8 [

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.